# Creating a Stripe Subscription via Java: POST /v1/customers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stripe-payments, resttemplate

I have this class to create a Stripe Subscription:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBearerAuth(apiTestKey);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    
        CreateSubscriptionRequest createSubscriptionRequest = CreateSubscriptionRequest.builder()
                .customer("cus_P5ZkW678nZi3d0K")
.object("customer")
                .items(ItemsRequest.builder()
                        .data(List.of(DatumRequest.builder()
                                .id(String.valueOf(1))
                                .build()))
                        .build())
                .build();
    
        final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(createSubscriptionRequest), headers);
    
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<CreateSubscriptionRequest> response
                = restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl + "subscriptions", HttpMethod.POST, entity, CreateSubscriptionRequest.class);
```

but I have this error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "{<EOL>  "error": {<EOL>    "code": "parameter_missing",<EOL>    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",<EOL>    "message": "Missing required param: customer.",<EOL>    "param": "customer",<EOL>    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_jyjNoqopJFlkH3?t=1701167766",<EOL>    "type": "invalid_request_error"<EOL>  }<EOL>}<EOL>"
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:103)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're sending an empty object to Stripe API. It might be that you're sending a JSON instead of [form-encoded params](https://stripe.com/docs/api). I would use the official [stripe-java](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java) package to [send requests to Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=java).